# AES-NI module missing in Fedora

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules, openssl

I would like to use full disk encryption in the future and wanted to test if my CPU has AES-NI support so I followed guide on [nixcraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-out-aes-ni-advanced-encryption-enabled-on-linux-system/).

It turns out that I do have support, but the kernel modules are missing.

```
$ sort -u /proc/crypto | grep module
module       : arc4
module       : ccm
module       : crc32c_intel
module       : crc32_pclmul
module       : crct10dif_pclmul
module       : kernel
```

When I try to load the modules (`sudo modprobe aesni_intel aes_x86_64`) the command exits with 0, but the modules are not listed in the `lsmod` output.

I have never solved (or pretty much encountered) any problems with kernel modules before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fedora, the aesni is build into the kernel. Check this,

`# cat /boot/config-4.2.6-301.fc23.x86_64 | grep AES_NI
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=y`

The blog you mentioned works for modules compiled to be loaded externally thats why you do not see it work as described.

The `openssl engine` command also loads openssl engines loaded externally and openssl also has aes for intel compiled in.

Here is the relevant bug with the exact details but for Fedora 18 and above